# If statement not triggering

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to make this code alternate between setting `i` as 56 and `i` as 0 I cant seem to get the second if statement to trigger. The first one works.

```
  while True:
        print 'is55 before if logic is' + str(is56)
        if is56 == True:
            i = 0 
            is56 = False 
            #print 'true statement' + str(i)
            print 'True is56 statement boolean is ' + str(is56)
        if is56 == False:   
            i = 56 
            is56 = True                
        print  'i is ' + str(i)
```

Comment: This code is not complete, please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any objections ?

```
while True:
    print 'is55 before if logic is' + str(is56)
    i = is56 = 0 if is56 else 56             
    print  'i is ' + str(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two separate `if`, so you enter the first one, set `is56` to `False`, and then immediately enter the second one and set it back to `True`. Instead, you could use an `else` clause:

```
while True:
    print 'is55 before if logic is' + str(is56)
    if is56:
        i = 0 
        is56 = False 
    else: # Here!
        i = 56 
        is56 = True                
    print  'i is ' + str(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The changes in the first `if` block are immediately reversed by the next one.

You want to replace the separate `if` blocks with a single `if/else` block.

On another note, you could simply use an [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) object to implement this:

```
from itertools import cycle

c = cycle([0, 56])

while True:
    i = next(c)
    print  'i is ' + str(i)
    # some code
```

Answer (score 0):

Without an `elif`, the original code, if working, would execute both blocks. Why not:

```
def print_i(i):
    print 'i is ' + str(i)

while True: 
    print_i(56)
    print_i(0)
```